# How to autofit widget size and position to a cell in QTreeWidget?

Tags: qt, delegates, qtablewidget, qtreewidget

I pragrammaticaly create a QTreeWidget.

Then I pragrammaticaly add some items.

Then I add two QLabel widgets to two items (QTreeWidgetItem) by

```
myTree->setItemWidget(item1, 0, myLabel1);
myTree->setItemWidget(item2, 0, myLabel2);
```

And then I try to resize the row of the item pragrammaticaly. 
If I use an

```
item1->setSizeHint(0, QSize(myWidth, myHeight) );
```

the row chaged. But myLabel1 is not.

If I use an

```
item1->setSizeHint(0, QSize(myWidth, myHeight) );
myLabel->resize(myWidth, myHeight);
```

everething is ok but the row of myLabel2 mis adjusting to label by position.

Can I do something to auto-adjusting a widget (by size and position) to a cell of QTreeWidget?

P.S. After any resizing of tree (resize by width or expand/collapse node) widgets  updates correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In view of the fact that autofit start after resizing QTreeWidget, there is some method inside that resize widgets in cells.
So I opened QTreeWidget description (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html) and red all of *Public Functions* and *Public Slots*. When I did not find any useful function I looked at a parent class (QTreeView). And found

```
myTree->resizeColumnToContent(0);
```

Call *resizeColumnToContent* after resizing any row in a QTreeWidget and widgets will be always fit to cells.

P.S. I am the OP.

Comment: Hi! While this may provide a solution to OP's question, code only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow. It is important for OP to understand why this is a solution as it will help them more in the long run and be more beneficial for future visitors of the site. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding/updating a widget as an item, for example:

```
QWidget* wdg = new QWidget;
QPushButton* btIcon = new QPushButton();
QLabel* lb = new QLabel();
QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(wdg);
layout->addWidget(btIcon);
layout->addWidget(lb);
layout->setAlignment( Qt::AlignCenter );
wdg->setLayout(layout);
myTree->setItemWidget(item1, 0, wdg);
```

Or just fill the tree with widgets

Comment: It's not working. The wdg heigth is fixed while the row heigth change. If wdg heigth is fixed then button (and label) heigth are fixed too.